# Как назвать человека, с которым когда-то переписывался по электронной почте?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика, синонимы, термины

"Знакомый" – не подходит: недостаточная эмоциональная связь.

Может, "корреспондент"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь о человеке, с которым *когда-то* переписывался, тогда можно поиграть с приставкой "экс", которая имеет значение "бывший", "отставной", "утративший прежнее положение" (см. [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81&all=x)).

- **экс-корреспондент** (да, одно из значений слова "корреспондент" — это тот, кто находится в переписке с кем-либо, см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82));
- **экс-заочник** (но тут важен контекст, иначе это можно понять и как "бывший учащийся на заочном отделении вуза", и как "бывший заключённый");
- **экс-сопереписчик** (но здесь тоже без контекста можно понять иначе: "бывший соучастник переписи книги" или "тот, кто вместе со мной проводил перепись населения");
- **экс-пенпал** (от англ. *pen pal* — "друг по переписке");
- **экс-пенфрэнд** (от англ. *pen friend* — также "друг по переписке") и т. д.

С последними двумя заимствованиями стоит быть осторожнее: их можно написать по-разному, поскольку пока что не устоялись в русском языке как термины.